# Arclength of intersection between 2 perpendicular cylinders.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, curves, geodesic

hi have 2 perpendicular cylinders that intersect (I read the resulting curve is called the Steinmetz curve).

$x^2+y^2=R_1^2$ and $y^2+z^2=R_2^2$, with $R_2\lt R_1$ and want to parametrize the length of their intersecting line as a function of $\theta$, where $\theta=arctan(z/y)$.

When my segment starts at $0$,  I find I get the following integral to solve in order to get the right relationship.

$l= R_2\int_0^\theta{\sqrt{\dfrac{R_1^2-R_2^2\cos^4\theta}{R_1^2-R_2^2\cos^2\theta}}}$. I thought it might involve Incomplete elliptical integrals but can't seem to find a way to transform it into one.

Any ideas? I thought it must be a textbook problem but apparently not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think the case of equal cylinders may be expressed in terms of elliptic integrals, otherwise i don't think so.

Comment: It may help finding $ \theta, \phi $ trig relation in spherical coordinates

Comment: really?? Aren't I essentially in spherical coordinates now?? I mean here $\theta$ is the azimuthal angle and there is no dependence on the polar angle...

Comment: Your integral is hyper-elliptic, but with suitable transformations it can in fact be reduced to standard elliptic integrals. The algebraic manipulations are somewhat of a pain to work through, however....

Comment: ah ha thought so!! Thanks David

Comment: @tired As it turns out, you don't even need elliptic integrals for the special case of equal radii. This special case may be handled with beta function machinery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arclength of these Steinmetz curves can indeed be reduced to elliptic integrals (*complete* elliptic integrals, in fact), but this is a **highly** non-trivial fact to prove for cylinders of unequal radii.

We find ultimately,

> $$\ell{\left(a,b\right)}=4\sqrt{a}\left(\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{a-b}\right)\,E{\left(\frac{\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{a-b}}{2\sqrt{a}}\right)}.$$

---

Let $a>b>0$ and define the ratio $c:=\frac{b}{a}$. Note $0<c<1$.

$$\begin{align}
\ell{\left(a,b\right)}
&=b\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{a^2-b^2\cos^4{\left(\varphi\right)}}{a^2-b^2\cos^2{\left(\varphi\right)}}}\,\mathrm{d}\varphi\\
&=b\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{a^2-b^2\sin^4{\left(\varphi\right)}}{a^2-b^2\sin^2{\left(\varphi\right)}}}\,\mathrm{d}\varphi\\
&=b\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{1-c^2\sin^4{\left(\varphi\right)}}{1-c^2\sin^2{\left(\varphi\right)}}}\,\mathrm{d}\varphi\\
&=4b\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1-c^2\sin^4{\left(\varphi\right)}}{1-c^2\sin^2{\left(\varphi\right)}}}\,\mathrm{d}\varphi\\
&=4b\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{1-c^2x^4}{\left(1-x^2\right)\left(1-c^2x^2\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}x;~~~\small{\left[\sin{\varphi}=x\right]}\\
&=\frac{4b}{\sqrt{c}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{c}}\sqrt{\frac{1-y^4}{\left(1-\frac{1}{c}y^2\right)\left(1-cy^2\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}y;~~~\small{\left[\sqrt{c}\,x=y\right]}\\
&=4\sqrt{ab}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{c}}\sqrt{\frac{1-y^4}{1+y^4-2\mu\,y^2}}\,\mathrm{d}y;~~~\small{\left[2\mu:=c+\frac{1}{c}\right]}\\
&=\small{4\sqrt{ab}\int_{1}^{\sqrt{\frac{1-c}{1+c}}}\sqrt{\frac{2x^2}{\left(\mu+1\right)x^4-\mu+1}}\cdot\frac{(-2x)\,\mathrm{d}x}{\left(1+x^2\right)\sqrt{1-x^4}};~~~\small{\left[\sqrt{\frac{1-y^2}{1+y^2}}=x\right]}}\\
&=8\sqrt{2ab}\int_{\sqrt{\frac{1-c}{1+c}}}^{1}\frac{x^2\,\mathrm{d}x}{\left(1+x^2\right)\sqrt{1-x^4}\sqrt{\left(\mu+1\right)x^4-\left(\mu-1\right)}}\\
&=8\sqrt{2ab}\int_{\sqrt{\frac{1-c}{1+c}}}^{1}\frac{x^2\,\mathrm{d}x}{\left(1+x^2\right)\sqrt{1-x^4}\sqrt{\frac{(1+c)^2}{2c}x^4-\frac{(1-c)^2}{2c}}}\\
&=\frac{16ab}{a+b}\int_{\sqrt{\frac{a-b}{a+b}}}^{1}\frac{x^2\,\mathrm{d}x}{\left(1+x^2\right)\sqrt{1-x^4}\sqrt{x^4-\left(\frac{a-b}{a+b}\right)^2}}\\
&=\frac{16ab}{a+b}\int_{\kappa^2}^{1}\frac{x^2\,\mathrm{d}x}{\left(1+x^2\right)\sqrt{\left(1-x^4\right)\left(x^4-\kappa^8\right)}};~~~\small{\left[\kappa:=\sqrt[4]{\frac{a-b}{a+b}}\right]}\\
&=8\,H{\left(a,b\right)}\int_{\kappa^2}^{1}\frac{x^2\,\mathrm{d}x}{\left(1+x^2\right)\sqrt{\left(1-x^4\right)\left(x^4-\kappa^8\right)}}\\
&=:8\,H{\left(a,b\right)}\,I{\left(\kappa\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

where in the last line above we've introduced the auxiliary function $I{\left(\kappa\right)}$ defined for $0<\kappa<1$ by the hyper-elliptic integral

$$I{\left(\kappa\right)}:=\int_{\kappa^2}^{1}\frac{x^2\,\mathrm{d}x}{\left(1+x^2\right)\sqrt{\left(1-x^4\right)\left(x^4-\kappa^8\right)}}.$$

Also note that $H{\left(a,b\right)}$ stands here for the harmonic mean of $a$ and $b$.

$$\begin{align}
I{\left(\kappa\right)}
&=\int_{\kappa^2}^{1}\frac{x^2\,\mathrm{d}x}{\left(1+x^2\right)\sqrt{\left(1-x^4\right)\left(x^4-\kappa^8\right)}}\\
&=\int_{\kappa^2}^{1}\frac{x^2\,\mathrm{d}x}{\left(1+x^2\right)\sqrt{-\kappa^8+\left(\kappa^8+1\right)x^4-x^8}}\\
&=\int_{\kappa^2}^{\frac{1}{\kappa^2}}\frac{\frac12\kappa\,\sqrt{w}\,\mathrm{d}w}{\left(1+\kappa^2w\right)\sqrt{-\kappa^4+\left(\kappa^8+1\right)w^2-\kappa^4w^4}};~~~\small{\left[x=\kappa\sqrt{w}\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{4\kappa}\int_{\kappa^2}^{\frac{1}{\kappa^2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\left(1+\kappa^2w\right)\sqrt{w}\sqrt{\left(\frac{\kappa^8+1}{4\kappa^4}\right)-\left(\frac{w^4+1}{4w^2}\right)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{4\kappa}\int_{\kappa^2}^{\frac{1}{\kappa^2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\left(1+\kappa^2w\right)\sqrt{w}\sqrt{\left(\frac{\kappa^4+1}{2\kappa^2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{w^2+1}{2w}\right)^2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{4\kappa}\int_{\kappa^2}^{\frac{1}{\kappa^2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\left(1+\kappa^2w\right)\sqrt{w}\sqrt{\alpha^2-\left(\frac{w^2+1}{2w}\right)^2}};~~~\small{\left[\alpha:=\frac{\kappa^4+1}{2\kappa^2}\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{4\kappa}\int_{\kappa^2}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\left(1+\kappa^2w\right)\sqrt{w}\sqrt{\alpha^2-\left(\frac{w^2+1}{2w}\right)^2}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{1}{4\kappa}\int_{1}^{\frac{1}{\kappa^2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\left(1+\kappa^2w\right)\sqrt{w}\sqrt{\alpha^2-\left(\frac{w^2+1}{2w}\right)^2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{4\kappa}\int_{\kappa^2}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\left(1+\kappa^2w\right)\sqrt{w}\sqrt{\alpha^2-\left(\frac{w^2+1}{2w}\right)^2}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{1}{4\kappa}\int_{\kappa^2}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\left(v+\kappa^2\right)\sqrt{v}\sqrt{\alpha^2-\left(\frac{v^2+1}{2v}\right)^2}};~~~\small{\left[\frac{1}{w}=v\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{4\kappa}\int_{\kappa^2}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\left(1+\kappa^2w\right)\sqrt{w}\sqrt{\alpha^2-\left(\frac{w^2+1}{2w}\right)^2}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{1}{4\kappa}\int_{\kappa^2}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\left(w+\kappa^2\right)\sqrt{w}\sqrt{\alpha^2-\left(\frac{w^2+1}{2w}\right)^2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{4\kappa}\int_{\kappa^2}^{1}\frac{\left(1+\kappa^2\right)\left(1+w\right)\,\mathrm{d}w}{\left(1+\kappa^2w\right)\left(\kappa^2+w\right)\sqrt{w}\sqrt{\alpha^2-\left(\frac{w^2+1}{2w}\right)^2}}\\
&=\frac{\kappa^2+1}{4\kappa}\int_{\kappa^2}^{1}\frac{\left(1+w\right)\,\mathrm{d}w}{\left(\kappa^2+w+\kappa^4w+\kappa^2w^2\right)\sqrt{w}\sqrt{\alpha^2-\left(\frac{w^2+1}{2w}\right)^2}}\\
&=\frac{\kappa^2+1}{4\kappa}\int_{\kappa^2}^{1}\frac{\left(1+w\right)\,\mathrm{d}w}{\left(\left(\kappa^4+1\right)w+\kappa^2\left(w^2+1\right)\right)\sqrt{w}\sqrt{\alpha^2-\left(\frac{w^2+1}{2w}\right)^2}}\\
&=\frac{\kappa^2+1}{4\kappa}\int_{\kappa^2}^{1}\frac{\left(1+w\right)\,\mathrm{d}w}{2\kappa^2w\left(\left(\frac{\kappa^4+1}{2\kappa^2}\right)+\left(\frac{w^2+1}{2w}\right)\right)\sqrt{w}\sqrt{\alpha^2-\left(\frac{w^2+1}{2w}\right)^2}}\\
&=\frac{\kappa^2+1}{8\kappa^3}\int_{\kappa^2}^{1}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{w}\right)\,\mathrm{d}w}{\left(\alpha+\left(\frac{w^2+1}{2w}\right)\right)\sqrt{w}\sqrt{\alpha^2-\left(\frac{w^2+1}{2w}\right)^2}}\\
&=\frac{\kappa^2+1}{8\kappa^3}\int_{\alpha-\sqrt{\alpha^2-1}}^{1}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{w}\right)\,\mathrm{d}w}{\left(\alpha+\left(\frac{w^2+1}{2w}\right)\right)\sqrt{w}\sqrt{\alpha^2-\left(\frac{w^2+1}{2w}\right)^2}}\\
&=:\frac{\kappa^2+1}{8\kappa^3}\,J{\left(\alpha\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

For $\alpha>1$,

$$\begin{align}
J{\left(\alpha\right)}
&=\int_{\alpha-\sqrt{\alpha^2-1}}^{1}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{w}\right)\,\mathrm{d}w}{\left(\alpha+\left(\frac{w^2+1}{2w}\right)\right)\sqrt{w}\sqrt{\alpha^2-\left(\frac{w^2+1}{2w}\right)^2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{1}^{\alpha}\frac{\left(1+u+\sqrt{u^2-1}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{u-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{u+1}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}u}{\left(\alpha+u\right)\sqrt{\alpha^2-u^2}};~~~\small{\left[w=u-\sqrt{u^2-1}\right]}\\
&=\sqrt{2}\int_{1}^{\alpha}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\left(\alpha+u\right)\sqrt{u-1}\sqrt{\alpha^2-u^2}}\\
&=\sqrt{2}\int_{1}^{\alpha}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{\left(\alpha-u\right)\left(u-1\right)\left(u+\alpha\right)^3}}\\
&=\sqrt{2}\,\mathcal{E}{\left(\alpha,1,-\alpha;1\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

where $\mathcal{E}{\left(A,B,C;U\right)}$ is an elliptic integral whose general evaluation in terms of standard elliptic integrals is given in the appendix below. One finds

$$\mathcal{E}{\left(A,B,C;U\right)}=\frac{2\,E{\left(\arcsin{\sqrt{\frac{A-U}{A-B}}},\sqrt{\frac{A-B}{A-C}}\right)}}{\left(B-C\right)\sqrt{A-C}}-\frac{2\sqrt{\frac{\left(A-U\right)\left(U-B\right)}{U-C}}}{\left(A-C\right)\left(B-C\right)}.$$

Setting $U=B=1\land A=\alpha\land C=-\alpha$, we have

$$\mathcal{E}{\left(\alpha,1,-\alpha;1\right)}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\left(1+\alpha\right)\sqrt{\alpha}}\,E{\left(\sqrt{\frac{\alpha-1}{2\alpha}}\right)}.$$

Hence,

$$\begin{align}
J{\left(\alpha\right)}
&=\sqrt{2}\,\mathcal{E}{\left(\alpha,1,-\alpha;1\right)}\\
&=\frac{2}{\left(1+\alpha\right)\sqrt{\alpha}}\,E{\left(\sqrt{\frac{\alpha-1}{2\alpha}}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

And hence,

$$\begin{align}
I{\left(\kappa\right)}
&=\frac{\kappa^2+1}{8\kappa^3}\,J{\left(\alpha\right)}\\
&=\frac{\kappa^2+1}{8\kappa^3}\cdot\frac{2}{\left(1+\alpha\right)\sqrt{\alpha}}\,E{\left(\sqrt{\frac{\alpha-1}{2\alpha}}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\kappa^2+1}{4\kappa^3}\cdot\frac{2\kappa^2}{\left(\kappa^2+1\right)^2\sqrt{\frac{1+\kappa^4}{2\kappa^2}}}\,E{\left(\frac{1-\kappa^2}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+\kappa^4}}\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\left(1+\kappa^2\right)\sqrt{1+\kappa^4}}\,E{\left(\frac{1-\kappa^2}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+\kappa^4}}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

And finally,

$$\begin{align}
\ell{\left(a,b\right)}
&=8\,H{\left(a,b\right)}\,I{\left(\kappa\right)}\\
&=\frac{8\,H{\left(a,b\right)}}{\sqrt{2}\left(1+\kappa^2\right)\sqrt{1+\kappa^4}}\,E{\left(\frac{1-\kappa^2}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+\kappa^4}}\right)}\\
&=\frac{16\,\frac{ab}{a+b}}{\sqrt{2}\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{a-b}{a+b}}\right)\sqrt{\frac{2a}{a+b}}}\,E{\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{\frac{a-b}{a+b}}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\frac{2a}{a+b}}}\right)}\\
&=\frac{8\sqrt{a}b}{\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{a-b}}\,E{\left(\frac{\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{a-b}}{2\sqrt{a}}\right)}\\
&=4\sqrt{a}\left(\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{a-b}\right)\,E{\left(\frac{\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{a-b}}{2\sqrt{a}}\right)}.\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

---

**Appendix:**

For $A>U\ge B>C$,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}{\left(A,B,C;U\right)}
&=\int_{U}^{A}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{\left(A-x\right)\left(x-B\right)\left(x-C\right)^3}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{A-U}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{y\left(A-B-y\right)\left(A-C-y\right)^3}};~~~\small{\left[A-x=y\right]}\\
&=\small{\int_{0}^{\frac{A-U}{A-B}}\frac{\left(A-B\right)\,\mathrm{d}z}{\sqrt{\left(A-B\right)^2z\left(1-z\right)\left(A-C-\left(A-B\right)z\right)^3}}};~~~\small{\left[\frac{y}{A-B}=z\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(A-C\right)^3}}\int_{0}^{\frac{A-U}{A-B}}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\sqrt{z\left(1-z\right)\left(1-\kappa^2z\right)^3}};~~~\small{\left[\kappa:=\sqrt{\frac{A-B}{A-C}}\right]}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\left(A-C\right)^3}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{A-U}{A-B}}}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\sqrt{\left(1-w^2\right)\left(1-\kappa^2w^2\right)^3}};~~~\small{\left[\sqrt{z}=w\right]}\\
&=\small{\frac{2}{\sqrt{\left(A-C\right)^3}}\int_{0}^{\sin{\psi}}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\sqrt{\left(1-w^2\right)\left(1-\kappa^2w^2\right)^3}}};~~~\small{\left[\psi:=\arcsin{\sqrt{\frac{A-U}{A-B}}}\right]}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\left(A-C\right)^3}}\int_{0}^{\psi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\varphi}{\sqrt{\left(1-\kappa^2\sin^2{\varphi}\right)^3}};~~~\small{\left[w=\sin{\varphi}\right]}.\\
\end{align}$$

Defining $\kappa^{\prime}:=\sqrt{1-\kappa^2}$,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}{\left(A,B,C;U\right)}
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\left(A-C\right)^3}}\int_{0}^{\psi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\varphi}{\sqrt{\left(1-\kappa^2\sin^2{\varphi}\right)^3}};~~~\small{\left[w=\sin{\varphi}\right]}\\
&=\small{\frac{2}{\sqrt{\left(A-C\right)^3}}\int_{0}^{\psi}\left[\frac{\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2{\varphi}}}{\kappa^{\prime\,2}}-\frac{\kappa^2}{\kappa^{\prime\,2}}\frac{1-2\sin^2{\varphi}+\kappa^2\sin^4{\varphi}}{\sqrt{\left(1-\kappa^2\sin^2{\varphi}\right)^3}}\right]\,\mathrm{d}\varphi}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\left(A-C\right)^3}}\frac{1}{\kappa^{\prime\,2}}\int_{0}^{\psi}\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2{\varphi}}\,\mathrm{d}\varphi\\
&~~~~~-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\left(A-C\right)^3}}\frac{\kappa^2}{\kappa^{\prime\,2}}\int_{0}^{\psi}\frac{1-2\sin^2{\varphi}+\kappa^2\sin^4{\varphi}}{\sqrt{\left(1-\kappa^2\sin^2{\varphi}\right)^3}}\,\mathrm{d}\varphi\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\left(A-C\right)^3}}\frac{1}{\kappa^{\prime\,2}}\,E{\left(\psi,\kappa\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\left(A-C\right)^3}}\frac{\kappa^2}{\kappa^{\prime\,2}}\int_{0}^{\psi}\frac{d}{d\varphi}\left[\frac{\sin{\varphi}\cos{\varphi}}{\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2{\varphi}}}\right]\,\mathrm{d}\varphi\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{A-C}}\frac{1}{\kappa^{\prime\,2}}\left[E{\left(\psi,\kappa\right)}-\frac{\kappa^2\sin{\psi}\cos{\psi}}{\sqrt{1-\kappa^2\sin^2{\psi}}}\right]\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\left(A-C\right)^3}}\cdot\frac{A-C}{B-C}\left[E{\left(\psi,\kappa\right)}-\frac{\left(\frac{A-B}{A-C}\right)\sqrt{\frac{A-U}{A-B}}\sqrt{\frac{U-B}{A-B}}}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{A-B}{A-C}\right)\left(\frac{A-U}{A-B}\right)}}\right]\\
&=\small{\frac{2}{\left(B-C\right)\sqrt{A-C}}\left[E{\left(\arcsin{\sqrt{\frac{A-U}{A-B}}},\sqrt{\frac{A-B}{A-C}}\right)}-\frac{\sqrt{A-U}\sqrt{U-B}}{\sqrt{A-C}\sqrt{U-C}}\right]}\\
&=\frac{2\,E{\left(\arcsin{\sqrt{\frac{A-U}{A-B}}},\sqrt{\frac{A-B}{A-C}}\right)}}{\left(B-C\right)\sqrt{A-C}}-\frac{2\sqrt{\frac{\left(A-U\right)\left(U-B\right)}{U-C}}}{\left(A-C\right)\left(B-C\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: wow!! that's tedious indeed!! I was trying to parametrize l vs theta though...  You set your max value to 2 pi here... 
 Is there a way to insert an arbitratry theta value as an upper integration bound in there?? I'll have to thoroughly read everything and see for myself if it works but if you know off the top of your head :)

Thanks again though and kudos that's phenomenal work!

Comment: @CharlesBrillon Sure, that should be a straightforward generalization once you've digested the derivation above. Just apply the exact same transformations starting from an integral with arbitrary  upper limit. The result is an incomplete elliptic integral like the one I evaluated in the appendix.